# How to view a post with firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on a posting website with firebase 9 and vue 3.

I've created the functionality so that you can post blogs, now I only so that if you click on one of the post you get directed to a new page with the post title and some description.
Everything works except the title in the viewpost page.

This is my code:

Home Page:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <div v-for="example in examples" :key="example.id">
      <router-link :example="example" :to="{ name: 'ViewPost', params: { id: example.id } }">
        {{ example.title }}
      </router-link>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import getCollection from "@/composables/getCollection";

export default {
  name: "Home",
  setup() {
    const { documents: examples } = getCollection("examples");
    return { examples };
  },
};
</script>
```

ViewPost:

```
<template>
  <h1>ViewPost</h1>
  <p>{{ example.title }}</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

GetCollection:

```
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue'

// firebase imports
import { db } from '../firebase/config'
import { collection, onSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore'

const getCollection = (c) => {
  const documents = ref(null)

  // collection reference
  let colRef = collection(db, c)

  const unsub = onSnapshot(colRef, snapshot => {
    let results = []
    snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
      results.push({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })
    })
    
    // update values
    documents.value = results
  })

  watchEffect((onInvalidate) => {
    onInvalidate(() => unsub());
  });

  return { documents }
}

export default getCollection
```

Router with history mode:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Create from '../views/Create.vue'
import ViewPost from '../views/ViewPost.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/create',
    name: 'Create',
    component: Create
  },
  {
    path: '/post/:id',
    name: 'ViewPost',
    component: ViewPost,
  },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

These are the errors I got in the google chrome console:

```
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6620 [Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of setup function 
  at <ViewPost onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< null > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
warn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6620
runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6620 


[Vue warn]: Unhandled error during execution of scheduler flush. This is likely a Vue internals bug. Please open an issue at https://new-issue.vuejs.org/?repo=vuejs/vue-next 
  at <ViewPost onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< null > > 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
warn @ runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6620
getDocument.js?d5ae:11 


Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'collection')
    at getDocument (getDocument.js?d5ae:11)
    at setup (ViewPost.vue?fc96:11)
    at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6737)
    at setupStatefulComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6346)
    at setupComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:6302)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4224)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4199)
    at patch (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:3791)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?5c40:4409)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js?a1e9:160)
```

Thanks a lot!
Emiel

Comment: Where is `example` defined in ViewPost component?

Comment: well, apparently it is not